# Avoid repetitive calls in Salesforce Community page

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

On my community page, I placed 8 different components and each component makes a SOQL call to retrieve account details. How can I avoid repetitive SOQL calls and store the results of 1st call so that they can be accessible by other components? For e.g., There is a concept of Session and application level variables which I don't see in Salesforce.
​​​​​​​
In Summary, the community page should be able to share variables or data between all components without making SOQL calls for the same object.

Thanks,